# How to change all href and src paths on webpack building?

Tags: javascript, webpack, pug-loader

I have a websites, written mostly in pug (html preprocessor). I use output.publicPath equal to '/' so I can run webpack in development mode and work easily, treating project folder as a root one, but every href, src and url is an absolute path. I want to change every path by adding some nodes (let's use '/path/to/' for example) in the begging, when I build project. For example, I have an image

```
img(src="/img/image.jpg")
```

And after I build this project, I want to receive this:

```html
<img src="/path/to/img/image.jpg">
```

And to receive the same with hrefs and urls.

I made a webpack build config and setted output.publicPath to '/path/to/' but it changed the pathes of linked css and js files:

```js
mode: "production",
  output: {
  publicPath: "/HTMLPractice/dist/"
}
```

I'll be glad to receive any solution, idea or recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `publicPath` on the `file-loader`, so long as the `file-loader` regex contains the image files.

In your `webpack.config.js` rules:

```
     {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          publicPath: 'some/path',
        },
      },
```

More info: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#publicpath